# Properties of infinity and $\pi$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Are the decimal points after $\pi$ a countable infinity or uncountable? Can I just map the first decimal point to the first natural number and nth decimal to nth natural number?

Comment: Yes, they are countable.  All you need to do is establish that there exists an injective map from the decimals to the natural numbers, and you have described such a map.

Comment: could you explain a situation with an uncountable set? I know a set is uncountable if there is not injective function from the set to the natural numbers? (besides the open interval)

Answer (score 2):

A decimal fraction always has a countable infinity of decimal positions after the decimal point. As you suggest, there is an $n$th decimal for every $n\in\mathbb N$.

(For a "terminating" decimal fraction, all of the decimals from a certain point onwards are simply $0$).

There are no decimals except for those with natural numbers as positions. In particular the *meaning* a a decimal fraction $N.d_1d_2d_3\ldots$ is the infinite sum
$$ N+ \frac{d_1}{10} + \frac{d_2}{10^2} + \frac{d_3}{10^3} + \cdots+ \frac{d_n}{10^n} + \cdots $$
and there's no power of 10 to put in the denominator of a term that would come *after* the first countable infinity of digits.